# Sort by name and then group by some boolean relationship? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, sorting

I have a list of named objects:

```
class NamedObject {
    public string name;
    public int value;
    public NamedObject(string name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

...

public static bool HasRelationship(NamedObject a, NamedObject b) {
    return a.value == b.value;
}

...

var objs = new List<NamedObject>();
objs.Add(new NamedObject("D", 1));
objs.Add(new NamedObject("Z", 2));
objs.Add(new NamedObject("Y", 3));
objs.Add(new NamedObject("A", 2));
objs.Add(new NamedObject("C", 1));
objs.Add(new NamedObject("Z", 1));
```

of which I would like to sort by name, and then sub-sort by a boolean relationship. For the purposes of this example the boolean relationship is `a.value == b.value`.

**Output List:**

- A (2)
- Z (2)
- C (1)
- D (1)
- Z (1)
- Y (3)

So sort by name, group by boolean relationship, sort sub-group by name.

**Edit:**

The above is a simplification of the actual sorting, in my application the `HasRelationship` function determines whether two orientations have symmetry. The orientations are named so that they appear in a logical order within the editor interface.

Here is a visualisation:

http://pbrd.co/16okFxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should join your list by itself since your *HasRelationship* method needs two objects.

```
var result = objs.OrderBy(x => x.name)
            .Join(objs, _ => true, _ => true, (l, r) => new { l, r, rel = HasRelationship(l, r) })
            .Where(x => x.rel)
            .SelectMany(x=>new []{x.l,x.r})
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Although this returns the list you expect, I can not say I understand your requirements clearly.

Comment: Indeed your solution does seem to provide to correct output! I have posted a fully commented answer which I hope will make better sense of my question. However, since your solution works and is more concise consider it accepted :) cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused by the question, I will try to be as clear as possible.

First it seems you want to sort NamedObjects by name, that's the clear and easy part. An order by should do the work.

And then you want to partiton it by an arbitrary predicate based on a pair of NamedObjects. I think that's the issue that arises the confusion.

The predicate you provide determines properties of pairs of NamedObjects, so now you are dealing with pairs. There's no unique answer to this question.

I understand you want to partition pairs by the predicate but you must understand that with a boolean partition you only will have two partitions ( relation is true or not), and no guaranteed order of values within the partition.

So at most you could get (sorted by name on the first term of the pair):

- pair(A,Z)(true)
- pair(A,C)(false)
- pair(A,D)(false)
- ...
- pair(C,D)(true)
- ...

The point is you can't order by pair relationship without implicitly deal with pairs. So to give you an answer I will assume:

- Relation may not be symmetric
- You want to sort by the first pair term name

With this context an answer could be. First get pairs.

```
var namedPairs = namedObjects.SelectMany(outerNamedObject =>
    namedObjects.Select(innerNamedObject => new
        {
            First = outerNamedObject,
            Second = innerNamedObject
        }));
```

Then we do the grouping

```
var partitionedNamedPairs = namedPairs.GroupBy(pair => 
    HasRelationship(pair.First, pair.Second));
```

After that, sort by first term name and then by the group key ( the relation partition )

```
var result = partitionedNamedPairs.SelectMany(
         grouping => grouping.Select(pair => new { pair, key = grouping.Key }))
     .OrderBy(keyedPair => keyedPair.pair.First.name)
     .ThenBy(keyedPair => keyedPair.key);
```

You could then use select to remove the second term of the pair, but i don't see the point of that, because your provided predicate is binary.

Comment: Sorry that my question is confusing. I have posted a working example of what feels like a hacky solution: http://hastebin.com/jepinidule.cs  I am going to experiment with what you have posted here since I do not understand it yet. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is fully commented and hopefully will help future readers of this question to understand the sorting process which was required.

The answer by @QtX was nice and concise, though it seems that people were having difficulty understanding what I was actually requesting, so sorry about that guys!

**Usage Example:**

```
var sortedObjs = objs.SortAndGroupByRelationship(obj => obj.name, HasRelationship);
```

**Extension method for sort and group:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortAndGroupByRelationship<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> objs, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Func<T, T, bool> relationship) where TKey : IComparable<TKey> {
    // Group items which are related.
    var groups = new List<List<T>>();
    foreach (var obj in objs) {
        bool grouped = false;

        // Attempt to place named object into an existing group.
        foreach (var group in groups)
            if (relationship(obj, group[0])) {
                group.Add(obj);
                grouped = true;
                break;
            }

        // Create new group for named object.
        if (!grouped) {
            var newGroup = new List<T>();
            newGroup.Add(obj);
            groups.Add(newGroup);
        }
    }

    // Sort objects within each group by name.
    foreach (var group in groups)
        group.Sort( (a, b) => keySelector(a).CompareTo(keySelector(b)) );

    // Sort groups by name.
    groups.Sort( (a, b) => keySelector(a[0]).CompareTo(keySelector(b[0])) );

    // Flatten groups into resulting array.
    var sortedList = new List<T>();
    foreach (var group in groups)
        sortedList.AddRange(group);
    return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = objs.GroupBy(x => x.value, (k, g) => g.OrderBy(x => x.name))
                 .OrderBy(g => g.First().name)
                 .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Returns exactly what you want, without using `HasRelationship` method.

Comment: The `HasRelationship` method is important for my specific application. Though the identity relationship is a nice simplification for this question.